# Use English in Equations and Hebrew in Regular Text

Tags: lyx, languages, hebrew

I use Lyx in Hebrew, which means regular text is written in Hebrew, but equations are of course written in English. I used to have an installation, which (I believe by accident during installation process) every time I entered any equation environment, my language was auto-set to English. Then, returning to regular text it was again auto-set to Hebrew.

This was very convenient, as it saved me the trouble of changing languages all the time, and of course there is zero use of Hebrew in math except Aleph for cardinality.

I now wonder whether there is a more conventional way to achieve this without trying to make random mutations to Lyx installation processes. Thanks!

Comment: This might be slightly related to the following recent feature request regarding Hebrew and language switching: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10514

Comment: Thanks, but these are two separate issues - one is direction of writing (RTL vs LTR), which indeed is annoying, and here it is about actually autoswitching the language itself inside math env.

Comment: In my installation of TeXlive, the switching is done automatically. See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382966/112191).

Comment: @AGoldMan how is this a duplicate when my question was from 11 months ago and your referred to one from 4 months ago?